# Is it a bad idea for my homepage to be in a sub-folder?

Tags: seo, directory, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should home page be just domain name or can it be in a folder?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25994/should-home-page-be-just-domain-name-or-can-it-be-in-a-folder)

I have just put my first website online :D
It's a revision website (that's how cool I am:p ).

All my content and different PHP scripts are in different folders, to keep it all organised. My Homepage and all the other scripts, css, php etc... are in a homepage folder.

Is this a really terrible idea? should it just be in the public_HTML folder loose?

I have done barley any SEO on my site, and it was on the second page of Google, but now seems to have gone to the third page. I've got META tags, but nothing else. Is it going so wrong because of the sub directory?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This answer should help you out http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25994/should-home-page-be-just-domain-name-or-can-it-be-in-a-folder/26007#26007